# Firebase: firebase.messaging() is not a function

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to set up `NodeJS Client Web App` from `FCM`. I have setup `firebase-admin` on the server side. While setting up the client to access tokens I am getting a `TypeError: firebase.messaging is not a function` error. From other solutions it seems like a compatibilty error between different FCM versions but still could fix it. Below is the html file I am using

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

  <script>
    console.log(firebase);

    const messaging = firebase.messaging();
    messaging.onTokenRefresh(function () {
      messaging.getToken()
        .then(function (refreshedToken) {
          console.log('Token refreshed.');
          console.log(refreshedToken);
          // // Indicate that the new Instance ID token has not yet been sent to the
          // // app server.
          // setTokenSentToServer(false);
          // // Send Instance ID token to app server.
          // sendTokenToServer(refreshedToken);
          // // [START_EXCLUDE]
          // // Display new Instance ID token and clear UI of all previous messages.
          // resetUI();
          // // [END_EXCLUDE]
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          console.log('Unable to retrieve refreshed token ', err);
          // showToken('Unable to retrieve refreshed token ', err);
        });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

How to correctly set up firebase on the client side?
EDIT: `console.log(firebase)` gives :

```
SDK_VERSION: "3.1.0", initializeApp: ƒ, app: ƒ, Promise: ƒ, …}
INTERNAL:{registerService: ƒ, createFirebaseNamespace: ƒ, extendNamespace: ƒ, createSubscribe: ƒ, ErrorFactory: ƒ, …}
Promise:ƒ Promise()
SDK_VERSION : "3.1.0"
User:ƒ (a,b,c)
app:ƒ a(a)
apps:(...)
auth:ƒ (c)
database:ƒ (c)
initializeApp:ƒ (a,c)
storage:ƒ (c)
get apps:ƒ ()
__proto__
:
Object
```

Comment: The firebase is loaded or not ?

Comment: yes, it is. I am getting an object with `console.log(firebase);`. But it doesn't have the `messaging()` function. I'll add that in the question.

Answer (score 11):

It looks like you didn't follow the basic integration steps from the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup).  There is an include for messaging:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.2.0/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
```

Also note that the latest version of the web client in 4.2.0.  You're on an old version.

Comment: I have, the html file I posted is from the documentation. Like I said, it is probably the version conflict, I'll try this and get back. Thanks.

Comment: What documentation are you referring to?  The one I showed is canonical.  Official Firebase docs don't show old versions of things.

Comment: Also note that I've included "firebase-messaging.js" and not just "firebase.js".

Comment: I followed documentation but this was not in it :/, then I came here searching

Answer (score 9):

You need to include `firebase-app.js` and `firebase-messaging.js` in your `html` file:

```
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.20.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.20.0/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try
replacing `import 'firebase/messaging';`
with `import 'firebase/compat/messaging';`

It worked for me